# Regex for url not enclosed in tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, contenteditable

I have a contenteditable div, when the user presses space or pastes into it, its content is searched for an url (via regex) that get substituted with:

`<a href="' + url + '" title="' + url + '" target="_blank" class="label label-info label-url" contenteditable="false">url: \'' + url + '\'</a>&nbsp;`

and it works.

The problem is that when you go on writing or pasting, the three urls in that `<a>` tag will get evaluted again and subsituted, causing havoc, so I need a way to avoid them from being evaluted, either by changing the regex (it should ignore url preceeded by `href="`, `title="` or `url: '`) or changing the js.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YUekd/

Comment: have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem is, that there is no negative lookbehind in JS regex engine. But you can use a callback function with the `replace` method to do that:

```
html = html.replace(
    /(href="|title="|url: )?(yoururlregex)/ig, 
    function($0, $1, $2) {
        return $1 
             ? $0 
             : '<a href="' + $2 + '" title="' + $2 + '">url: ' + $2 + '</a>';
    }
);
```

I replaced your URL regex with a constant string to make it clearer, you can substitute your regex into the braces.

EDIT: Where to place `match`:

```
    function($0, $1, $2) {
        if ($1) {
            return $0;
        } else {
            match = true;
            return '<a href="' + $2 + '" title="' + $2 + '">url: ' + $2 + '</a>';
        }
    }
```

Comment: cool, I got it to work, where would you place my original match = true; line tho?

Comment: I think you can leave out the `match` check, but to do less HTML inserting, I added a version of the callback function with the `match` variable set.

Comment: just to understand what's going on: $2 is the url, $1 is first parenthesis match (either href,title or url), and $0 is the combination of both right?

Comment: I also had to change title=" to title="? in your regex cause ie8 doesn't like to place that attribute value between quotes for some weird reason :S

Comment: Yes, $0 is the full match, $1 the first parenthesis and $2 the second.

Answer (score 1):

You can reprocess all, you transform your `<a></a>` on a text back, so you redo all the process.

Comment: You can try this `$that.html($that.html().replace(new RegExp("<a href=\"(.*?)\".*?\/a>"), "$1"));` as the first line of the function `highlightUrl`. So this is going to normalize your html.